# Why am I getting ESM updates 1 year into a LTS release?

Tags: apt, upgrade, imagemagick, esm, ubuntu-pro

From my knowledge, ESM messages should not appear until 5 years into an LTS release
but I am getting these messages when running `apt upgrade`.

I removed apt ESM hook after backing it up and the message is removed.

Why did the updates for these packages stop one year into this LTS release? I use packages like `imagemagick` daily.

Also, should I restore the ESM hook in case this is just an error and updates will return?

[image: screenshot of terminal showing ESM message]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The packages you are seeing packages in esm-apps during the Standard Support period are patched Universe packages.

The use of ESM (Extended Security Maintenance) repositories changed with the late 2022 launch of Ubuntu Pro, replacing the older Ubuntu Advantage product.

Under (old) Ubuntu Advantage, ESM was only for security patches in the Main repository for the five years after the end of standard support.

Under (new) Ubuntu Pro, ESM keeps the same extra-five-years of Main --AND-- adds security patches in the Universe repository for the full 10 years. Previously the community (not Canonical) was responsible for Universe patches, so sometimes they happened and sometimes they didn't.

- Keep in mind that Pro is a proprietary product, and that the ESM repositories are private. The volunteers here at AskUbuntu are not the customer service department for Pro, have no special insight into the product or how it works, and cannot help with account problems nor technical support for it.